# How to override standard ObjectMapper when working with @SpringBootTest?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-boot-test, applicationcontext, mockmvc

Let's say I have a test class. Here I want to load a custom app context with only 1 bean and then autowire it.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = InnerWebConfig.class)
public class TarifControllerJsonTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private CustomBean bean;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testObjectMapper")
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        TarifControllerJson controller = new CustomContoller(bean);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
                .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        String url = "/urlToControllerEndpoint";
        Request request = new Request();

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(url)
                                                      .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request))
                                                      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();
        int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        assertEquals(200, status);
    }
}
```

InnerWegConfig.class:

```
@Configuration
public class InnerWebConfig {
    @Bean("testObjectMapper")
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new CustomObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

The bean is autowired succesfully and I can use it in scope of TarifControllerJsonTest class. The main problem is that Spring internally still uses default ObjectMapper when dealing with ser/deserialization (E.g. when validating request and passing it to the controller).

Do I miss something or/and do something completely wrong? Overriding bean doesn't work here. Would really appreciate if you can help here.

UPD: I also tried to configure spring converters

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class InnerWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        final AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new TarifServiceObjectMapper());
        converters.add(converter);
    }
}
```

Comment: The described matches your configuration! (you didn't miss anything, but your assumptions seem wrong.) If you want to replace objectmapper for test (why would you want that?), (one solution) "just" annotate your test class with `@ActiveProfiles("mytest")` and your (test) configuration with `@Profile("mytest")`.

Comment: Hi @xerx593 I don't want to replace objectMapper for tests (it should be not different from the one which is set when spring-boot app is actually running). I just to use my custom mapper, whereas default mapper is being used. I don't know the exact reasson.

Comment: I tried to configure spring converters (e.g. MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, pls check updated post)

But it doesn't seem to be the solution.

Comment: And the one you gave me in the comment above doesn't help too

Comment: you need a "test mapper" (only!) to feed mockMvc (it doesn't even have to be a spring bean) ...and the application should (always) use that, whatever it uses... ;)

Comment: as soon as you understand (or can name) your problem, we will find one! ;)

Comment: and if you want to re-use (the application mapper) for tests, "just" autowire it (without qualifier, without additional config;)

Comment: and probably most problem: `TarifControllerJson controller = new CustomContoller(bean);` Does nothing! (after that line ...garbage collected...as your mockbean)

Comment: please take that 15 minutes! https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/